# Значение оператора as

Tags: c#

```
if (!(sender as RadioButton).Checked)

TextBox tb = Controls["textBox" + i] as TextBox;
```

Что такое sender as и as?

Comment: @Mr-Al, не забывайте принимать верные ответы!

Answer (score 6):

Оператор **as** используется для выполнения определенных типов преобразований между совместимыми ссылочными типами и возвращает null в случае если преобразование невозможно.
**sender** в вашем случае, скорей всего источник события.

Answer (score 1):

Проще-говоря оператор `as` - это оператор явного приведения совместимых ссылочных типов.

На [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) есть хороший пример его работы:

```
class csrefKeywordsOperators
{
    class Base
    {
        public override string  ToString()
        {
           return "Base";
        }
    }
    class Derived : Base 
    { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Derived d = new Derived();

            Base b = d as Base;
            if (b != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

В данном примере класс наследник приводится к типу его родителя.

`sender` - имеет отношение к событиям о которых можно почитать на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8627sbea.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Но, опять-же вкратце:
Практически каждое событие имеет рекомендуемую всеми сигнатуру выглядящую как

```
void foo(EventArgs, object)
```

Где EventArgs - параметры функции, а object - объект который это событие вызвал.
Соответственно `EventArgs /*параметры функции*/` называют как `arg`, а `object /*вызвавший объект*/` как `sender`. 
т.к. object - это нетипизированный объект, для работы с которым необходимо приведения типа.

Именно это, осмелюсь предположить, и происходит в вашем вопросе.

**Объект вызвавший событие приводится к определенному типу для работы с ним.**

Надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос. Удачи!

Comment: иногда стоит смотреть на дату вопроса :-)

Comment: @Grundy упс... что-то я не обратил внимания))